# How to get table name for a simple bag?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Having a bag mapped like this:

```
<bag name="Addresses" table="address" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="employee"/>
  <element column="address"/>
</bag>
```

How can I get at runtime the table name in which the addresses are stored?

If the collections generic type was a NHibernate mapped class I could have done it like this:

```
var tableName = (sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(itemType) as SingleTableEntityPersister).TableName;
```

But in this case the collections generic type is just a string and I couldn't find any way to retrieve the table name from the metadata.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would be interesting to know where you need this. Nevertheless

```
var metaData = sf.GetClassMetadata("containingType");
var c = (CollectionType)metaData.PropertyTypes[Array.IndexOf(metaData.PropertyNames, "collectionPropertyName")];
var tablename = c.GetAssociatedJoinable((ISessionFactoryImplementor)sf).TableName;
```

Comment: The reason I need the metadata for entities is so I can use bulk insert/update with `NpgsqlCopyIn`.

Comment: oh cool, i needed and maybe still need something like this for im/export of data

Comment: it is nice, much faster than other options for bulk insert/update, about 2.7% of normal insert time according to this article: http://www.depesz.com/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
var classMetadata= sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(parentClass)) as SingleTableEntityPersister;
var key = classMetadata.RootEntityName + "." + propertyName;
var allCollectionMetadata = sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata();
var childTableName = (allCollectionMetadata[key] as BasicCollectionPersister).TableName;
```